# Had Slim Pickens and Kubrick worked together prior to Dr Strangelove?

Tags: casting, stanley-kubrick

Slim Pickens was cast in *Dr. Strangelove* somewhat last-minute. Originally, Peter Sellers had been slated to play the bomber pilot, along with his three other roles, but a knee injury required him to bow out of the fourth role.

Pickens had been in *One-Eyed Jacks* a few years before. That movie had originally had Stanley Kubrick in the director’s chair, but Kubrick had clashed with its star, Marlon Brando, who went on to direct it himself.

Had Pickens already joined the *One-Eyed Jacks* cast when Kubrick was still directing it? Had they worked together, albeit briefly, before Pickens joined *Dr. Strangelove*?

Answer (score 2):

Kubrick only has the following credits in iMDB prior to *Strangelove*:

- *Lolita* (1962)
- *Spartacus* (1960)
- *Paths of Glory* (1957)
- *The Killing* (1956)
- *Killer's Kiss* (1955)
- *The Seafarers* (1953)
- *Fear and Desire* (1953)
- *Omnibus* (1952)
- *Day of the Fight* (1951)
- *Flying Padre* (1951)

Also according to iMDB, Slim Pickens had not worked on any of these projects.

If iMDB is accurate, **NO**.

Furthermore, [this article](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/63436/15-things-you-might-not-know-about-dr-strangelove) seems to imply that Kubrick tapped Pickens for the first time, and Pickens until then had largely worked in Westerns.  Kubrick didn't have any Westerns to my knowledge.